# Symfony2: How to force HTTPS for the whole app?

Tags: symfony, https, nginx

Is it possible to force https for the whole application without defining it for all 100 routes/firewall rules?

We tried to force https on webserver level, but symfony2 still tries to redirect to http and generates some weird links (http://[...]:443).

I read the configuration documentation but didn't find anything for that. All cookbook entries are also only for enabling it per route/security rule.

Comment: How did you force it on webserver level?

Comment: Why force the app to do it, just let nginx do the change to https

Comment: Please post your security config.

Answer (score 0):

[How to force HTTPS or HTTP for Different URLs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/force_https.html)

> The Security component provides a way to enforce HTTPs via the
>   `requires_channel` setting. This alternative method is better suited
>   to secure an "area" of your website (all URLs under /admin) or when
>   you want to secure URLs defined in a third party bundle.

```
access_control:
    - path: ^/secure
      roles: ROLE_ADMIN
      requires_channel: https
```

Comment: As I said, I don't want to do it for every security rule but for the whole website.

Answer (score 0):

It seems we misconfigured our webserver. For reference, here is the now working config:

```
    server {
            listen x.x.x.x:80;
            server_name domain.tld;
            listen      80;

            location / {
                    rewrite     ^(.*)   https://domain.tld$1 permanent;
            }
    }

    server {
            gzip                on;
            gzip_types          text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml text/javascript image/x-icon;
            gzip_min_length     1000;
            gzip_comp_level     6;
            gzip_http_version   1.0;
            gzip_vary           on;
            gzip_proxied        expired no-cache no-store private auth;
            gzip_disable        msie6;

            listen x.x.x.x:443;

            ssl         on;
            ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/wildcard_ssl/cert.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/wildcard_ssl/cert.key;

            server_name domain.tld;

            root /var/www/domain.tld/current/web/;

            access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.tld/access.log main;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/domain.tld/error.log;

            rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

            location / {
                    index app.php;
                    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
            }
            location @rewriteapp {
                    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
            }

            location @long_time {
                    fastcgi_pass   tldpass;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root/app.php;
                    fastcgi_param  HTTPS              on;

                    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
            }
            location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_pass   tldpass;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
                    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    fastcgi_param  HTTPS              on;
                    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;

                    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.tld/php-only.log;
            }

            location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|htc)$ {
                    expires     31d;
                    add_header  Cache-Control private;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

on security.yaml

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/, requires_channel: https, host: ^www\.domain\.com$ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Force the whole app to handle only ssl requests with https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioSecurityBundle

```
nelmio_security:
    forced_ssl: ~
```

Make router generate `https` urls by default:

```
parameters:
    router.request_context.scheme: 'https'
```